# django allauth github organizations restriction

Tags: django, github, single-sign-on, django-allauth

i have created a Django webapp, and i want to use allauth to create a sso for github.

I have set it up, and it works fine. But now all github users can login to my webapp. I want to restrict it only to my github organization. So that all users of my organization can login to the web app and users which are not in the organization cant login.

Is there any option from allauth to realize this? i have checked the allauth documentation, but i can't find any option for that.

Or is there any other way which i can use to realize my requirement?

Comment: can you please provide details like `settings.py` please?

Comment: my settings.py look like this:

SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'github': {
        'APP': {
            'client_id': 'xxxx',
            'secret': 'xxxxx',
            'scope': ['read:user', 'read:email'],
        }
    },

}